# Cache Redis 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, redis

it is impossible to make a cache for this query :

```
Cache::remember('Article.'.$cat_id.$order_by.$sort, $cache_minute, function() use($cat_id, $order_by, $sort)
{
    return Article::where('cat_id','=', $cat_id)
    ->where('published_at', '<=', new DateTime('now'))
    ->with('cat', 'comments')
    ->orderBy($order_by, $sort)
    ->paginate(Config::get('view.paginate_items'))
});
```

It appears that a closure is serialized.

Please, an idea about the reason or how to cache ?

Comment: I was facing the same issue.. removing the pagination worked for me (was not critical in my case).  

`Cache::remember('Article.'.$cat_id.$order_by.$sort, $cache_minute, function() use($cat_id, $order_by, $sort)
{
    return Article::where('cat_id','=', $cat_id)
    ->where('published_at', '<=', new DateTime('now'))
    ->with('cat', 'comments')
    ->orderBy($order_by, $sort)
    ->get()
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can user the ->remember() function to cache a query x amount of minutes.

This subject is explained [over here by Franz](http://www.develophp.org/2013/05/laravel-4-query-results-caching/)

Comment: Hello Nico (It's Nicolab ;) ), I tried but it did not cached queries. Look http://laravel.fr/forums/impossible-de-mettre-en-cache-le-resultat-dune-requete-t37